# Riemann Sphere Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been posed with the task of explaining, if $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of points on the Riemann Sphere which converges to $(0,0,1)$ why does the corresponding sequence $\{z_n\}$ in the complex plane go to inf? Also, why is the converse true as well?

I understand the problem abstractly as to why this is, but am having trouble articulating this into a proof form.

Comment: I guess you need to know the correspondence between the two spaces.  Then elementary calculus.

Comment: Consider a small disk around (0,0,1). What does that map to in the complex plane?